# Insert bulk Parent and Children rows using SQL Query

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

We receive bulk data from our customers in a spread sheet. I loaded them in a temporary table as of now. I tried to normalize the data and create a parent table and each parent to have 4 or 5 child rows. Is there a way to insert all the parents and their children using queries? I dont want to write an Application to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're specifically looking to write only queries to perform this task, check out the following article that outlines a way to set up a linked server to an excel doc.

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/read-import-excel-file-p01.aspx

If you get this set up correctly (which can be a pain) it's as easy as querying the data directly.